# Add conditionally a class to cart items and order items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

I would like to style Woocommerce cart and order items differently when the related product uses [Woocommerce Product add-ons 3+](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/) plugin custom fields, so I need add class conditionally *(to cart items and order items)*.

But I can not get it work, using `_wc_pao_addon_name` meta key to work with. Here is my code:

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'add_product_addon_classes', 10, 4 );
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'add_cart_addon_classes', 10, 4 );

  function add_cart_addon_classes ( $class, $cart_item, $values  ) {

    if ( isset( $values['_wc_pao_addon_name'] ) ) {
        $class = $class . ' fl-addon-item';
    }

    return $class;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Related: [Pricing options, image swatches, and more have arrived in Product Add-Ons 3.0](https://woocommerce.com/posts/pricing-options-image-swatches-product-add-ons-3-0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make one function that works for both hook, as they have different hook arguments:

- The hook `woocommerce_cart_item_class` uses `$class`, `$cart_item` and `$cart_item_key` arguments
- The hook `woocommerce_order_item_class` uses `$class`, `$item` and `$order` arguments

As you see your `$values['_wc_pao_addon_name']` can't work in your code.

**1) Cart items:**

To check and get the correct meta_key used by Woocommerce Product add-ons plugin, you will use first the testing hooked function added at the end of this answer…

Once you will find the right `meta_key` you will replace in the following code `addon_parent_id` by the right `meta_key`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'additional_class_to_cart_item_classes', 10, 3 );
function additional_class_to_cart_item_classes ( $class, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['addon_parent_id'] ) ) {
        $class .= ' fl-addon-item';
    }

    return $class;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should work for cart and checkout.

---

**2) For orders items** *(Order received, order view, Order pay and email notifications)*:

It's more complicated as you need to know how `_wc_pao_addon_name` is saved in order items. For that you will need to take a look in your database table `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` searching for a `meta_key` that match with `_wc_pao_addon_name`.

Once you will find the right `meta_key` you will replace in the following code `_wc_pao_addon_name` by the right `meta_key`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'additional_class_to_order_item_classes', 10, 3 );
function additional_class_to_order_item_classes ( $class, $item, $order ) {
    if ( $item->get_meta('_wc_pao_addon_name') ) {
        $class .= ' fl-addon-item';
    }

    return $class;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should work for order items.

---

#### Check and get the correct cart custom metadata *(testing only)*:

To find out in cart object what is the correct meta key for custom meta data added by plugins as Woocommerce Product add-ons, you will use the following *(that will display in cart page the cart items raw data)*:

```
// Testing and getting cart item raw data
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', function(){
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // Output cart item raw data
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($cart_item); echo '</pre>';
    }
}, 987 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).

Comment: Thanks you! For mail / orders items code works fine (I looked at database and meta_key is exactly _wc_pao_addon_name). But code for cart doesnt work (Isnt it because order is not created yet?). Thanks you

Comment: You are genius as everytime .) Right meta seems to be addon_parent_id. Thanks you very much!